# Проблема с библиотеками Python

Tags: python, библиотека

Скачал с интернета такую сеть как "facenet".
Начал устанавливать для неё библиотеки, установил, запускаю и такие ошибки (на фото).
Python 3.6.0[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: попробуйте почитать доку по библиотеке, как она устанавливается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решил, библиотеки были слишком новые дня питона 3.6, поставил 3.7 и всё ок